# Where these white spots in the preview image of the shader come from?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders

[image]

The preview image of the shader has some white dots. Is this due to e.g. uncoloured vertices?

Comment: if i increase light source sun size then object looks good but the preview panel circle still has some white dots on a certain region.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a **preview** for the material, and the white dots are reflection render.

Don't worry about it.